# Are non-Muslims allowed to participate in Hajj or Umrah?

Tags: hajj, umrah

Non-Muslims: No, they aren't permitted to take part in Hajj and Umrah. It is the case that Mecca, the capital city Mecca in which these pilgrimages occur, is restricted to non-Muslims. This is because the Saudi Arabian government strictly enforces the restrictions.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This post can hardly be identified as a question,since there's no question asked here in the question section. See [ask] and please don't misuse our site to advertise your site or any other website (I've edited your post accordingly). For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]